# MySQL - Accessing all relational data in one query

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a relation mysql database setup. and I want to pull all the data for one item from the main row and all the relational data (ie multiple associated rows) in one query. What's the easiest/best way to do this aside from a multiple JOIN statement in one query?

The tables and query currently used are below.

**Relational data**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| value_id | value_site_id | value_field_set_id | value_field_setting_id | value_parent_id | value_parent_type | value_value |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Primary Table**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| item_id | item_site_id | item_country_id | item_category_id | etc etc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**And the Query is**

```
SELECT fs.field_variable_name, fs.field_type, fv.value_value, fv.value_parent_id
FROM T_field_values AS fv 
    INNER JOIN T_field_settings AS fs ON fv.value_field_setting_id=fs.field_id
WHERE fv.value_parent_type=:type &&
    fv.value_parent_id=:id;
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the tables you are querying? or some of your current SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use multiple `JOIN` clauses, one for each relationship.

Don't fear the `JOIN`. It's standard practice.

The other way is to use a sub query for each one, but the query optimizer will turn them into JOINs anyway.

The `JOIN` query will be easier to read.

**EDIT**

I see, you have some form of EAV tables. Your case is a bit complex, and without the complete structure (T_field_settings is missing) and some sample data, I'm not going to attempt to provide the exact query, but take a look at my previous answer here, on how to use a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769470/sql-re-arrange-a-table-via-query/2769509#2769509) to get results from a EAV table. It should get you going on the right track.

Comment: I only said not join because it could be up to `n` pieces of data with no limit.

Comment: @buggedcom, I expanded my answer because you can use sub queries also. If you provide more details, we can provide examples. It won't be unlimited. You can't have more joins than rows.